# How to copy files without the full path with grunt.js?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I want to copy the content of `/pckg` to `/dist` with grunt.js.
Here is the structure:

```
  |-- folder1
  |     |
  |     |-- folder2
  |           |
  |           |-- pckg
  |                 |
  |                 |--myfolder
  |                 |    |
  |                 |    |-- myfiles
  |                 |
  |                 |--myfiles
  |
  |
  |-- dist
        |
        |--myfolder
        |   |
        |   |-- myfiles
        |
        |--myfiles
```

Here's my `Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Package configuration
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Metadata
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    //Copy files
    copy: {
      main: {
        expand: true,
        src: 'folder1/folder2/pckg/**',
        dest: 'dest/'
      }
    }

  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "copy" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);
};
```

When I run Grunt, it keep the path. It copy everything in `dit/folder1/folder2/pckg`.
What is wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here's what I've used:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'folder1/folder2/pckg/',
    src: ['**'],
    dest: 'dist/'
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The documentation uses the `cwd` param but never explains it.

Comment: grunt is such a "great" tool.. documentation is almost on the same level

Answer (score 16):

use flatten:true

```
copy: {
    main: {
        files: [ 
            {expand: true, src: ['components/xxx/*'], dest: 'dist/', flatten: true}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the folder structure inside `pckg`. Is it ok with this config ?

Comment: @alienlebarge, faltten dose not keep the folder structure inside pckg.