# grunt-contrib-copy files are not copied to the correct locaiton

Tags: grunt-contrib-copy

I am trying to copy cshtml files to the production folder.
the files are located in the path:
a\b\c\d and the destination is a\b\e

the task is

```
 copy: {
        copyCSHtml: {
            src: '../NGWeb/client/app/appComponents/**/*.cshtml',
            dest: '../NGWeb/client/app/dist/',
        }
    }
```

the actual result that i get is
a\b\a\b\c\d
1. why does it create the whole trailing path?
2. why it copy one directory before?

is it possible to get a\b\e\d?

---

```
  cwd: '../NGWeb/client/app/appComponents/',
            src: [ '**/*.cshtml' ],
            dest: '../NGWeb/client/app/dist',
            expand: true
```

Comment: Try to set the working directory (cwd) to `../NGWeb/client/app/appComponents/` or `../NGWeb/client/app/`, what suits you better.

Comment: I had the same problem.  Someone else asked a similar question, and an answer that worked for me was found [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19310984/2872239